# how to get original data from normalized array

Tags: python, preprocessor, normalize

I have a simple piece of code given below which normalize array in terms of row.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

X = np.asarray([[-1,2,1],
                [4,1,2]], dtype=np.float)

X_normalized = preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l2')
```

Can you please help me to convert X-normalized to X again?

Comment: Why did you normalize it? You've thrown away information you can't get back.

Comment: I will apply SVM to data set which has both continuous and categorical attribute. I am following a paper that suggests me to apply one hot encoder to categorical data and then normalize all data based on samples. But later, I need to get back original attributes.

Comment: Can't you just reference X again, rather than X_normalized? You can't "unnormaize" a vector.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot recover X from nothing more than the normalized version.  Consider the trivial case of several data sets, each with 2 different elements:

```
[3, 4]
[-18, 20]
[0, 0.0001]
```

Each of these normalizes to the *same* data set:

```
[-1, 1]
```

The mapping is not a bijection: it's a many-to-one.  Thus, it's not uniquely invertable.

However, you can recover the original set with a couple of simple techniques:

1. Keep the original data set intact (yes, that easy).
2. Store the normalization parameters: mean and standard deviation (or its square, the variance).  This gives you the linear equation that transforms each original element into a normalized element; it's trivial to invert that equation.

Answer (score 1):

All the scalers in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing have inverse_transform method designed just for that.

For example, to scale and un-scale your DataFrame with MinMaxScaler you could do:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df)
unscaled = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled)
```

Just bear in mind that the transform function (and fit_transform as well) return a numpy.array, and not a pandas.Dataframe.

```
[Refrence][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382716/how-can-i-cleanly-normalize-data-and-then-unnormalize-it-later/43383700
```