# Return normalize variable by range to the original values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset (`df`):

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1),
                 x2=c(1, 10, 5, 8, 3))
```

Normalize variable by range and create the `df_mod` object:

```
library(dplyr)
df_mod <- df%>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("x")), 
           funs((. - min(., na.rm = T))/(max(., na.rm = T) - min(., na.rm = T))))
```

But, now I'd like to know, what kind the function do I need to use to convert `df_mod` to the original `df` again?

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First the code for df_mod should be:

```
library(dplyr)
df_mod <- df%>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"), ~(. - min(., na.rm = TRUE))/(max(., na.rm = T) - min(., na.rm = T))))
```

- Second I don't think that you can return normalized variable by range to original values. See here [how to get original data from normalized array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919816/how-to-get-original-data-from-normalized-array)